# Why don't my webparts show?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-parts

I have been following a tutoral on webparts here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337551/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-Web-Parts

And followed it example and copied the code across into my default.aspx, everyone was working until I modified the webpart headings and then ran it, at that point nothing from the web parts showed on the page at all. I undid my changes and tried again, now I can't get the webparts to show at all. I did the tutorial again, completely refreshing everything but nothing will show.

I have tried to do a simple test by adding some from the toolbox but as you may have guessed, when I run it they do not show.

```
        <asp:WebPartManager ID="WebPartManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:WebPartManager>
        <br />
        <asp:WebPartZone ID="WebPartZone1" runat="server">
            <ZoneTemplate>
                test
            </ZoneTemplate>
        </asp:WebPartZone>
        <asp:CatalogZone ID="CatalogZone1" runat="server"></asp:CatalogZone>
```

Comment: What did you modify with regards your WebPart headings?

Comment: I changed (for example) this HeaderText="Pick a Day" to "Widget Area 1" but now I have changed it all back nothing works.

Comment: Try creating a new Web Part from scratch. If that works, it may be because of a GUID (unique identifier) that is assigned to every Web part.

Comment: @MarloC The above code is from the one I attempted to created from scratch.